# How much items should I check to determine if the delivery is invalid?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory

Given delivery with $5000$ items.
An item may be invalid or valid (with a probability of half of each option).
If there are $3\%$ invalid items - all the delivery  is invalid.
How much items should I check to determine if the delivery is invalid?

I don't have idea how to going about it and I will be happy for help.

Comment: What probabilities of incorrectly determining that a valid delivery is invalid, and what probability of incorrectly determining that an invalid delivery is valid, are acceptable to you? In the worst case, you check 4850 valid items and then the remaining 150 are invalid, whereupon the delivery is invalid but you needed to check every single item to discover this. (Unless by "there is a 1/2 probability of a given item being valid or invalid" you mean that 2500 of the items are valid and 2500 are invalid.)

Comment: And if the *a priori* probability of an item being invalid is really 0.5 then the probability that a delivery of 5000 items will have fewer than 150 invalid items is very very small since this is more than 60 standard deviations away from the mean (which is 2500).